# Why I don't see update of my angular project with firefox?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox, hottowel

I took the hot towel template from  [John Papa's blog](http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/) and running it with VS 2013.

So, I am working on the apps, but wierdly, I don't see the updates of my project, when I run it with firefox (lastest version), but it works well with Internet explorer  (also lastest version). And I don't understand why.

Even a little update in an html file, is not visible in Firefox, but it is in IE.

Does somebody have any explanations to this?

I am not sure if this is the right stack overflow section for this question, if it is not, I will delete it, and rewrite it into the right one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reload the page ?

If it works free the cache after each update.

I hope my answer fit you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebug, make sure your html file is getting loaded, also disable browser caching. Don't forget to reload the entire page after any updates.
If / when you have success pls post your solution.